# How to return the response body from javascript function execution - in java?

Tags: javascript, java

Does anyone know how to return the response body from javascript function execution - in java as a string?

I tried this :

http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-http-response-body-as-a-string/

It's actually very helpful , but it only returns the HTML code of my page . There's a button on that page which calls JS function and I need to retrieve the network HTTP response after executing the function .

Is there any way to do this ?

====================================================================

I need something like this :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get(URL);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("JS({something})");
```

and then after the script is executed I need something to retrieve the content of the response

Is that possible at all ?

Comment: What do you mean, the network HTTP response after executing the function? Does the function send a HTTP request?

Comment: Open Chrome > Open Console  > load the page > click on button ("Function.js" is executed) > in console click "Network" tab > find the "Function.js" > click on it > it opens the "Preview" tab > next to it is the "Response" tab > I need to retrieve all the content of the "Response" tab

Comment: Are you expecting to run the AJAX code which part of HTML of your page?

Comment: I need something like this :

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get(URL);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("JS({something})");
and then after the script is executed I need something to retrieve the content of the response

Is that possible at all ?